# Must I call iter.get_next when using Tensorflow's Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have converted code over from a queue based system to tensorflow's dataset.  After the conversion, I'm seeing a loss of accuracy and times have increased.  I am attributing this to an incorrect implementation on my end and I am currently trying to troubleshoot what may be the issue. Now through trial and error in this conversion I made some assumptions based on a number of articles and examples I came across and I just wanted to make sure that my current implementation is correct and that my assumptions were as well.

Previously I had a huge number of images and I would batch them into a queue, then pop off the queue with my 100 images, perform processing and summarization and then continue. This loading into memory via the queue I believed was potentially causing a bottleneck, so when I heard about the Dataset API, I figured it was worth a look.  So I now retrieve all image info and and pass it to my method where I then perform the batch via the Dataset batch method.  The before and after are shown below. I had read that it wasn't necessary to call iter.get_next on the dataset as the ops would call it automatically, however with the accuracy I'm seeing at the end, I'm hesitant on whether this is true or not.  Currently as you can see, I just pass the iter.initializer as an op to sess.run with my other ops and pass the feed_dict.  Any insight would be helpful as I'm somewhat new to this.  Thanks!

**Previous sample function when using queue:**
*(Mind you I would queue the images into a blob object and pass that subset to this method)*

```
def get_summary(self, sess, images, labels, weights, keep_prob = 1.0):
        feed_dict = {self._input_images: images, self._input_labels: labels,
                     self._input_weights: weights, self._is_training: False}
        summary, acc = sess.run([self._summary_op, self._accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        return summary, acc
```

**Current sample function using Dataset API:**
*(Now prior to calling this, I populate my blob object with all data and use the batch functionality below -- notice that I never make a call to iter.get_next())*

```
def get_summary(self, sess, images, labels, weights, keep_prob = 1.0, batch_size=32):
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self._input_images, self._input_labels,
                                                      self._input_weights)).repeat().batch(batch_size)

        iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
        feed_dict = {self._input_images: images, self._input_labels: labels,
                     self._input_weights: weights, self._is_training: False}
        _, summary, acc = sess.run([iter.initializer, self._summary_op, self._accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        return summary, acc
```

Comment: From that code snippet, it looks like you never use the values from `iter` so it should be having no effect on your summaries. For example, you should be able to delete the lines that create the iterator, and remove `iter.initializer` from the list passed to `sess.run()` and get the same result. This suggests that the error is somewhere else in your program, and we’ll need to see more of the code to understand why it isn’t working.

Comment: Thanks mrry for the response. That answered my question and get_next() must be called. I instead removed the logic in the location I showed above and I instead have performed the population of my dataset in the parent code block and then just pass the images, labels, etc as I did before. If you provide you above comment as an answer, I will accept it as the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that code snippet, it looks like you never use the values from `iter` so it should be having no effect on your summaries. For example, you should be able to delete the lines that create the iterator, and remove `iter.initializer` from the list passed to `sess.run()` and get the same result.

To answer the broader question of "Must I call `iter.get_next()`?": in graph-based TensorFlow there must be a dataflow connection between the `tf.data.Iterator` and the tensor/operation that you pass to `sess.run()` in order to consume values from that iterator. If you are using the **low-level** TensorFlow API, the easiest way to achieve this is to call `iter.get_next()` to get one or more `tf.Tensor` objects, and then use those tensors as the input to your model.

However, if you are using the **high-level** `tf.estimator` API, your `input_fn` can return a `tf.data.Dataset` without creating a `tf.data.Iterator` (or calling `Iterator.get_next()`, and the Estimator API will take care of creating the iterator and calling `get_next()` for you.